# How should i use .then and .catch in an axios call in Vue JavaScript App?

Tags: vue.js, promise, vuejs2, axios

Im calling this code on mounted in a Vue App

```
mounted() {
this.isMounted = true;

axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').then((response) => {
  console.log("Response is" + response)

}).catch(function(error) {
  // handle error
  console.log("Error is: " + error);
})
```

}

And always get the same error: Error: Request failed with status code 404

I have testd the API and works perfectly, always response with a 200.
I do not know what im doing wrong

Comment: Are you sure its https?

Comment: Yes, its https, the problem was the MockAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
mounted () {
    this.isMounted = true;
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Response is" + response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)

      })
  }
```

or

```
    mounted () {  
    axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
              .then(function (response) {
               console.log("Response is" + response)
              }.bind(this))
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
              })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error.
I had activated a mock adpter so every call was handled by this MockAdapter.

```
var mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
```

So every call fails if it is not in the mockCalls list.
Is there any way to have a MockAdapter for only some specific calls? For example you have to use two different API and only want to have mocked one of them